# Mule API timing out for one path but works for fine for other path

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I have a Mule API which calls another system. The call to the another system are included in a common flow and parameters are set dynamically.
The high level API paths are:

```
GET /invoices
POST /workorder
```

Despite having a common configuration, the calls made to /workorder path are successful, but calls to "invoices" get request timed out error. I tried both requests in Postman too and it is the same behaviour.
Any idea how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: The question is too abstract. You need to provide details for reproduction and explain the implementation. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Like @aled mentioned the question is too broad,

What I understand there's a mule api (lets call it a proc) which calls another system api (sys).

Cause for this is that the target is taking more time than the source is willing to wait for the response.

The first things to do would be to increase the `response timeout` at proc requestor configuration, the default response timeout is 10s (10000 milliseconds), increase this value till it no more gives this error at proc.

If the error is returned from sys api when calling from postman, do the same for sys api for its request configuration.

Reference - [Request Configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-documentation#request)

Hope this helps.